# Failing to install puppet

Tags: puppet

Let's say I have 2 fresh Ubuntu 14.04 VMs. I wish to make one a puppet master and the other a puppet client. I following the official puppet install guide, which is very simple (linked down the bottom). In essence, you install puppetmaster on one server and puppet on the other. Then on the master, you append the hostname(s) of the master to the [main] section of /etc/puppet/puppet.conf under as "dns_alt_names". Then run "puppet master --verbose --no-daemonize" to attempt to generate the ca certs.

The issue is that as soon as I run that last command, my terminal hangs on executing that. The output I get is:

```
Warning: Setting templatedir is deprecated. See http://links.puppetlabs.com/env-settings-deprecations
   (at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:1139:in `issue_deprecation_warning')
Notice: Starting Puppet master version 3.7.3
```

If I comment out "templatedir", it will remove the first warning and still hang on the second line. Any idea what is going on here? On a brand new machine and doing only a few basic steps from the official install guide, I don't know what limitation I am hitting here.

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_debian_ubuntu.html
https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/post_install.html

Comment: `Notice: Starting Puppet master` is the normal and expected output. You're done. Go on to the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You linked to the documentation, but you seem to have missed the part, right under the command it told you to run, which says:

> This will create the CA certificate and the puppet master certificate, with the appropriate DNS names included. Once it says `Notice: Starting Puppet master version <VERSION>`, type ctrl-C to kill the process.

Comment: Man, that blows my mind. I read 80% of that and skipped over the ctrl-C bit. The fact that the output also inserts in a line break afterwards (uncommon for programs that run in the shell), made me more suspicious that it had hung. And that's despite the fact that I was expecting it to start up a daemon process in the first place. Thanks Michael.

Comment: Well, that's what `--no-daemonize` does. The point of this step is to have it do its initial setup of the certificates, and then stop the server again. I also recommend plenty of sleep.